# STL multiset setting insertion order C++

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

I am using a multiset to store a collection of objects ordered, I am using operator< to establish the order criteria, but I am doing something wrong because when I iterate through the multiset printing a trace, I can see that they are not ordered at all.... I'm really blocked with this issue...

I try to simplify my code here:

```
class CellSearch
{
    public:
        bool operator<(const CellSearch & C) const;
        int getF() const        { return _G + _H; }
    private:
        int _G;
        int _H;
}
...
bool CellSearch::operator< (const CellSearch& C) const
{
    return (this->getF() < C.getF());
}
```

the way I declare the multiset is:

```
std::multiset<CellSearch*> myOpenList;
```

and I insert a new element this way:

```
....
CellSearch *actualSearch = new CellSearch(start);
addOpenList(actualSearch, myOpenList);
```

And here is the function:

```
void Grid::addOpenList(CellSearch* actual, std::multiset<CellSearch*>& openList)
{
    openList.insert(actual);
}
```

Is my first time using multiset...actually is my first container that is not a vector :) Can you see something wrong here?

I tried to summarize the code, I hope not too much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your multiset is storing **pointers** to objects. As a result, for comparison it compares **pointers**, rather than the objects itself.

To make it work in current form, you need to put **objects** themselves into multiset. Another option is to provide a custom comparator to set, which would know to dereference a pointer and compare the actual object - but this is inferior in this case, as I do not see any reason to store pointers at all.

It is also better to implement `operator <` as a free-function rather than the class member.

If you are set on having pointers in your container, this is how you should do it:

```
template<class KEY>
struct pointer_compare {
    bool operator()(const KEY* lhs, const KEY* rhs) const {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
}

std::multiset<Search*, pointer_compare<Search>> myOpenList
```

Comment: thank you for the advices!! :) anyway, could you please give an example of how could make a comparison dereferencing the pointer to compare the object?

Comment: thank you very much! I will consider the option of not to store pointers, but it was very interesting for mw to learn also the way to compare it dereferencing pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're working not with the set of `CellSearch` objects, but pointers to them, which makes the comparator work with pointers.

Here is the generic solution which you could reuse for other pointer comparisons:

```
template<class T>
struct PointerComparator {
    bool operator()(const T *a, const T *b) const {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};

std::multiset<CellSearch*, PointerComparator<CellSearch> > myOpenList;
```

This way you still have your `operator <` defined for `CellSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a cell less functor like this:

```
class cmpCell
{
    bool operator()(CellSearch* a, CellSearch* b)
    {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};
```

And then use it when declare the multiset:

```
std::multiset<CellSearch*, cmpCell> myOpenList;
```